# Calculating Variable Prices on Shopify Based on an Affine Formula with User Input

Tags: shopify, price, shopify-api, shopify-template, shopify-storefront-api

I'm currently working on a Shopify store and facing a challenge related to product pricing. I'm looking to implement a system where the price of a product varies based on an affine formula, and this formula needs to take into account a value specified by the user.

The formula I have in mind is as follows:

Price= Initial_Cost*Length/4
​

I want the user to be able to input a value (for example, the length in meters) on the frontend of my Shopify store, and have the price calculated using this formula.

The challenge is that manipulating prices on Shopify can be complex, and I'm not sure of the best approach to integrate this custom pricing logic.

Does anyone have advice or specific examples on how to implement this on Shopify, avoiding the use of third-party apps?

Thank you very much for your assistance!

I haven't tried anything yet. I'm seeking guidance on how to approach the implementation of a variable pricing system.

Answer (score 1):

The best option for implementing a custom variable pricing system on Shopify, without resorting to third-party apps, is to create a custom app. This will allow you to integrate your specific pricing logic seamlessly into your store. Here's a step-by-step guide on how you can achieve this:

1. Create a Private App:

   In your Shopify admin, navigate to Settings > Apps. Scroll down to
   the bottom and click on 'Manage private apps.' Create a new private
   app to get the API credentials needed for communication between your
   app and Shopify.
2. Set Up the Backend Logic:

   Develop a backend system that can receive user input (e.g., length
   in meters) and calculate the price based on your specified formula
   (Price = Initial_Cost * Length / 4​). Use the Shopify API to create
   a draft order with the calculated price. You can refer to the
   Shopify API documentation for details on creating draft orders.
3. Integrate the Frontend:

   On your Shopify store's frontend, implement a user interface that
   allows customers to input the relevant value (e.g., length in
   meters). Use JavaScript to capture this input and send it to your
   custom backend for price calculation.
4. Handle the Checkout Process:

   When a customer is ready to make a purchase, use the Shopify API to
   convert the draft order into a finalized order for seamless
   checkout.

By following these steps, you'll have a tailored solution that meets your specific pricing requirements without relying on third-party apps. Keep in mind that maintaining and updating your custom app will be your responsibility, so periodically check for updates to the Shopify API and make adjustments as needed.